# Windows service stopped after a day

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have written a windows service that fetch some data from a database and perform some functions every minute. I have a timer setup in the initialize code segment.

```
public WindowsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
        System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
        timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //StartProcess();
    }
```

After the deployment it worked without any issue. But when the date is changed to next day (eg:deployed on 29th June and the current date is 30th June), the scheduler is not performing. After I do a service restart manually, it performed as normal. What can be the issue with the timer?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive your timer is getting garbage collected. Declare the timer variable outside of the function so it never goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for you response. But this did not workout for me